# How to convert javascript array of objects to object of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

So I have the flowing javascript array

```
const oldData = [
             {
              "id":1,
              "Name":"test1",
              "Value":"abc"
             },
             {
              "id":2,
              "Name":"test2",
              "Value":"abc"
             },
             {
              "id":3,
              "Name":"test3",
              "Value":"xyz"
             },
            ]
```

and I want to convert it to something that looks like like this :

```
const newData = {
             {
              "id":1,
              "Name":"test1",
              "Value":"abc"
             },
             {
              "id":2,
              "Name":"test2",
              "Value":"abc"
             },
             {
              "id":3,
              "Name":"test3",
              "Value":"xyz"
             },
            }
```

Also , does this kind of object have a specific name ?

I tried the following :

```
const newData = await { ...oldData };
```

Comment: you wanted result is not valid without keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expected result is not valid Javascript object. You need to add keys for nested objects. For example:

```js
const newData = {
             0: {
              "id":1,
              "Name":"test1",
              "Value":"abc"
             },
             1: {
              "id":2,
              "Name":"test2",
              "Value":"abc"
             },
             2: {
              "id":3,
              "Name":"test3",
              "Value":"xyz"
             },
            }
```

Also await is not necessary. It's used for asynchronous actions.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to get is not valid json. An object always has a key to a value.

You could use Object.assign:

```
Object.assign({}, [
             {
              "id":1,
              "Name":"test1",
              "Value":"abc"
             },
             {
              "id":2,
              "Name":"test2",
              "Value":"abc"
             },
             {
              "id":3,
              "Name":"test3",
              "Value":"xyz"
             },
            ]);
```

The output will be

```
{
  "0": {
    "id": 1,
    "Name": "test1",
    "Value": "abc"
  },
  "1": {
    "id": 2,
    "Name": "test2",
    "Value": "abc"
  },
  "2": {
    "id": 3,
    "Name": "test3",
    "Value": "xyz"
  }
}
```